# Does Anthony Bloch have a kinship with Felix Bloch?

Tags: mathematicians, physicists

I would like to know whether [Anthony Bloch](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eabloch/) is a descendant of [Felix Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Bloch) or not. The [Anthony Bloch's page on The Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=33933) only shows his advisory relationships, not kinships.

<sub>Meta: [Is it ok to ask whether a person is a descendants of a scientist?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/65)</sub>

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate to just write to Anthony Bloch and ask, rather than ask on a public forum (I disagree with the answer given on meta).

Comment: Is it because you worry about that this is a private issue? If both persons are dead, then there is no way to ask them. Can you elaborate on why you disagree with that answer?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And if both persons are dead, I see no issue -- but it is not at all clear to me that Anthony Bloch is dead. If he is not, why have you not written to him?

Comment: Well, Anthony is not Felix's son, his children are [listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Bloch#Early_life,_education,_and_family) and were all born in 1940s. And considering that Anthony got his bachelor's in 1977 I doubt that any of them was old enough in late 1950-s to make him Felix's grandson.